# Dexie database locations

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I see from an earlier question that Dexie data is local to a single browser. Is there a way to access each browser's Dexie data?

I know I can access each browser's IndexedDB SQLite database directly and probably find the Dexie-stored data that way. I was just hoping there was a way to use Dexie code in one browser to look at any other browser's Dexie data.

Thanks you. And thanks to the crew building Dexie. It's a fantastic tool.

Answer (score 2):

Dexie is just a wrapper around indexedDB, which is implemented differently in every browser. Unlike WebSQL, it's typically not being stored in sqlite but in other browser-proprietary storage. And there's defenitely no way to access it from one browser to another. I suppose what you might be looking for is a sync solution. Have a look at [sync-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-client) and [sync-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-server). These integrate with Dexie and can make sure to keep your data in sync between browsers and devices.

Note: You need dexie 2.0-beta (soon stable release) in order to use sync-client and sync-server.

Comment: Thank you for that precise answer. Exactly what I wanted to know. 
I am definitely looking forward to dexie2 and trying out the syncs.